# Alamofire DownloadRequest validate and get the response data from the server

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have the following method

```
fileprivate func performDownloadRequest(_ request: DownloadRequest) {
request
      .validate()
      .downloadProgress { (progress: Progress) in
        ...
      }
      .response { response in 
        ...
```

where the `response` is `'(DefaultDownloadResponse) -> Void'`.

How can I make this to be `'(DownloadResponse) -> Void'` ? Note the `DefaultDownloadResponse` vs `DownloadResponse`.

The reason I want this is because the `DownloadResponse` has

```
/// The result of response serialization.
public let result: Result<Value>
```

and I am hoping to retrieve the JSON data sent by the server to display a custom text for the user. `DefaultDownloadResponse` does not have response data.

thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line, if you want a `Result` type, you're going to have to use `responseJSON`. But you can't do that with a simple `DownloadRequest`. This presents a few possible options:

1. If you really want to use a download request, you'll have specify the destination for the downloaded file when you create the `DownloadRequest`, using the `to` parameter, e.g.

   ```
   // you may have to create the directory if it hasn't been created yet

   try! FileManager.default.url(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

   // then you can use it:

   let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .downloadsDirectory)
   let req = Alamofire.download("http://httpbin.org/get", to: destination)
   perform(download: req)
   ```

   And then:

   ```
   func perform(download request: DownloadRequest) {
       request
           .validate()
           .downloadProgress { progress in
               print(progress)
           }
           .responseJSON { response in
               switch response.result {
               case .success(let value): print(value)
               case .failure(let error): print(error)
               }
       }
   }
   ```

   If you do this, you may want to remove that file at `response.destinationURL` when you're done with it.
2. IMHO, the theoretical advantage of download tasks is that the peak memory usage is lower. But if you're just going to turn around and load the contents of that file into some JSON object, I think that diminishes any advantage yielded by download tasks. So, the question is why not use data task, instead? You can just do a `DataRequest`:

   ```
   let req = Alamofire.request("http://httpbin.org/get")
   perform(get: req)
   ```

   And then:

   ```
   func perform(get request: DataRequest) {
       request
           .validate()
           .downloadProgress { progress in
               print(progress)
           }
           .responseJSON { response in
               switch response.result {
               case .success(let value): print(value)
               case .failure(let error): print(error)
               }
       }
   }
   ```

Personally, I'd lean towards a data task rather than the download task for JSON unless there's some reason you need it (e.g. background sessions), but it's up to you.

Comment: thanks Rob. I won't load the content of the file into a JSON, I would only capture the JSON response of the server when there is an error, so I can display a customized error message to the user that is constructed on the server side.